# How to create a WAR out of a eclipse project, while minifying all css and js files?

Tags: eclipse, maven, ant, eclipse-plugin, minify

I have a Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse and was wondering if there is a way I can create a WAR and in between minify all my `js` and `css` files.

Supposing my project file structure is

```
iscCSM
    |
    |
    infa9
    |
    |
    csm--ACProxy--include--acproxy--js
    |                       |       |
    |                       css     *.js
    |                       |
    |                       *.css
    |
    |
    |
    view--include--js--custom
    |       |       |       |
    *.html  |       *.js    *.js
    *.jsp   css
            |
            *.css
```

**Update**

After googling I got this maven plugin [Cactus](https://github.com/nbabinski/Cactus#in-downloads-cactus-pluginjar-was-built-using-maven-3-so-to-use-it-you-need-to-have-3rd-maven-version-but-you-can-easily-build-source-code-using-any-maven-version-starting-from-2-and-it-will-be-working) but I am having problem in configuring pom.xml file to use cactus plugin as given in the same [tutorial](https://github.com/nbabinski/Cactus#in-downloads-cactus-pluginjar-was-built-using-maven-3-so-to-use-it-you-need-to-have-3rd-maven-version-but-you-can-easily-build-source-code-using-any-maven-version-starting-from-2-and-it-will-be-working) Can somebody help me which pom.xml I need to modify?

I followed the tutorial and reached the stage where string `BUILD SUCCESS` appears, but m unable to move forward. Please help.

Comment: Where is the relationship to Maven?

Comment: @khmarbaise: I mentioned MAVEN & ANT tag in order to find people who have done it with them

Answer (score 4):

Web Resource Optimizer for Java (wro4j) is what you are looking for 
http://code.google.com/p/wro4j/.

It has support for js, css minifcation, with multiple minificators implementations, and also has support for less,sass, and coffeescript processor.

You can use it as:

- maven plugin
- standalone application
- as library in yours web aplication as ServletFilter - which is nice feater to use during development.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for, let me see if I am able to set it up. Thanks :)

Comment: It should be pretty simple to set it up, and documentation is pretty good. I use it in my project.

Comment: Do I need to convert my `Dynamic Web Project`s to `Maven Project` in order to build it?

Comment: If you want to use wro4j-maven-plugin you need to convert it to maven project, I would recommend you to do that.